# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected - Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to make an internet checker , but I don't know what's the problem with this PinvokeStackImbalance. Actually, the code was made for Visual Basic 2008, But I`m using Visual Basic 2010.

WebTest = CBool(InternetGetConnectedState(dwflags, 0&))

Where's the problem? Btw, it's a module.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of the Import used?

Answer (score 5):

You will get that MDA warning when you used a bad declaration for the function.  Which is pretty common in VB.NET, there are a lot of old VB6 declarations floating around on the Internet that will not work in VB.NET.  A sure sign of trouble is this particular function, it takes two arguments of type DWORD, if you see **Long** in the declaration then you've got a bad VB6 one.

Get reasonably reliable declarations from the Pinvoke Interop Assistant tool or the pinvoke.net web site:

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" _
                     (ByRef lpdwFlags As Int32, ByVal dwReserved As Int32) As Boolean

Private Enum ConnectionStates
    Modem = &H1
    LAN = &H2
    Proxy = &H4
    RasInstalled = &H10
    Offline = &H20
    Configured = &H40
End Enum
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

1. Debug - Exceptions - Managed Debugging Assistants

and then uncheck the options for:

1. ContextSwitchDeadlock
2. PInvokeStackImbalance

After that, no more messages.